# How to update class when filtering in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a portfolio and filtering my projects using .map().

Everything works well but I would like the filter buttons (inside the class .portfolio_labels) to remain a certain color when clicked on, ideally by assigning them a class when clicked, and then removing it when another filter is clicked. This is easy in vanilla Javascript but I'm having trouble incorporating it into the React app I have so far.

This is what I have:

```
function Projects() {
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState("all");
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setProjects(portfolio);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setProjects([]);

    const filtered = portfolio.map(p => ({
      ...p,
      filtered: p.category.includes(filter)
    }));
    setProjects(filtered);
  }, [filter]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="portfolio">
        <div className="portfolio__labels">
          <a active={filter === "all"} onClick={() => setFilter("all")}>
            All
          </a>
          <a
            active={filter === "frontend"}
            onClick={() => setFilter("frontend")}
          >
            Frontend Development
          </a>
          <a
            active={filter === "3d"}
            onClick={() => setFilter("3d")}
          >
            3D Modeling
          </a>
          <a
            active={filter === "branding"}
            onClick={() => setFilter("branding")}
          >
            Branding
          </a>
        </div>
        <div className="portfolio__container">
          <ul>
            {projects.map(item =>
              item.filtered === true ? 
              <li key={item.name} className='card'>
                  <Link className='card_path' to={item.source}>
                    <h1>{item.title}</h1>
                    <p>{item.description}</p>
                    <div className="card_preview">
                      <img src={item.preview} />
                      <img src={item.overlay} />
                    </div>
                    <span>{item.tools}</span>
                  </Link>
              </li> : ""
            )} 
          </ul>
        </div>    
      </div>

    </>
  );
}

export default Projects;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this dynamically handling the className using the `filter` value and the ternary operation `? :`

Assign className property to each `<a>` element and assign 'selected-link' or  'default-link' depending on if the link is active on not.

Check out the updated code below

```
  <div className="portfolio__labels">
     <a active={filter === "all"} onClick={() => setFilter("all")} className={filter === "all" ? 'selected-link' :'default-link'}>
         All
     </a>
     <a
        active={filter === "frontend"}
        onClick={() => setFilter("frontend")}
        className={filter === "frontend" ? 'selected-link' :'default-link'}
     >
        Frontend Development
      </a>
      <a
        active={filter === "3d"}
        onClick={() => setFilter("3d")}
        className={filter === "3d" ? 'selected-link' :'default-link'}
      >
         3D Modeling
     </a>
     <a
       active={filter === "branding"}
       onClick={() => setFilter("branding")}
       className={filter === "branding" ? 'selected-link' :'default-link'}
     >
       Branding
    </a>
 </div>
```